# getSelectedIndex() is showing same index for same numbers JavaFX

Tags: listview, javafx-8

so I'm creating a program that has a ListView and when I click on the items in its list it was to show the index of the assigned values ​​and pass it to a label, but for repeated numbers it shows the same index.

[image]

[image]

and it will always show the index of the first number I click on

[[image]

[image]

I searched the internet and I didn't find anything about this problem, if anyone can help me I would be very grateful.

Below is part of my code:

```
@FXML
void initialize() {

    CreateVet();

    // Definindo e configurndo os valores do spinner (min, max e inicial)
    SpinnerValueFactory<Integer> spinValue = new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(0, 9);
    spinValue.setValue(0);

    spin.setValueFactory(spinValue);

    listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> arg0, Number arg1, Number arg2) {

            select = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();

            if (select < 0){
                select = 0;
            }

            String selectTxt = Integer.toString(select);
            lblVet.setText("[ " + selectTxt + " ]");
        }
    });
}



    @FXML
    void btnAdcClick(ActionEvent event) {

        // Passando o valor do spinner para uma variável
        int spinNum = spin.getValue();

        // Definindo a opção selecionada com o valor do spinner
        vet[select] = spinNum;

        // MétodoS para limpar a lista atual e adicionar uma nova lista
        ClearLists();
        ListViewAdd();
    }

     void ListViewAdd() {
            // for loop to rewrite the vectors and pass them to the array
            for (int i = 0; i <= vet.length - 1; i++) {
                arrayList.add(vet[i]);
            }

            // Passing array values ​​to listView
            listView.getItems().addAll(arrayList);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your spinner, it is not passing the numbers and then the index is not caught and generates an error. try to rewrite

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).